# How to invoke a method findLargest from Oracle Java Tutorials (Using an Interface as a Type)

Tags: java

I'm studying oracle tutorials and have a few questions regarding the chapter Using an "Interface as a Type" [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) so I try to understand **how to invoke the method findLargest**.

I've tried to modify a bit source code to get the better understanding, but nothing helps :(

here is my code:

```
public class RectanglePlus implements Relatable {

    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;

    public RectanglePlus() {
    }

    public RectanglePlus(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    // a method for computing the area of the rectangle
    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    // a method required to implement the Relatable interface

    public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
        RectanglePlus otherRect = (RectanglePlus) other;
        if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // and here is the method that i cant invoke
    public RectanglePlus findLargest(RectanglePlus object1,
            RectanglePlus object2) {
        Relatable obj1 = (Relatable) object1;
        Relatable obj2 = (Relatable) object2;
        if ((obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) > 0) {
            return object1;
        } else {
            return object2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RectanglePlus test1 = new RectanglePlus(10, 20);
        RectanglePlus test2 = new RectanglePlus(20, 20);
    }
}
```

So, how can I invoke findLarge method on order to compare test1 and test 2? (I know it doesn't make sense to find the largest object since I know it from the method isLargerThan, but I just try to understand a principle)

Its not a static method so I cant just say "RectanglePlus.findLarger(test1, test2)".

How I do that?

Comment: one way is test1.findLargest(test1, test2) (or) test2.findLargest(test1, test2). In general findLargest should take one parameter and do comparison with this. then you can call findLargest using test1.findLargest(test2) which compares current object test1 with parameter test2.

Comment: yep, thats was the first thing taht i've tried, it also compiles without errors but then I see on the output oracleinterfaces.RectanglePlus@e48e1b  (oracle interfaces is the name of the main class, but I only compile this file)

Comment: are you sure? I think oracleinterfaces is package.

Comment: oracleinterfaces.RectanglePlus@e48e1b means it returned RectanglePlus object. May be do toString()  while printing instead of just printing the object. EDIT: Override toString method in RectanglePlus class with whatever you want to print, then you will get values instead of object.

Comment: Yes, thats was the issue!  I've just added an instance field **name** to this class and than said it should give me the name of the largest object. It works! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `findLargest` is not `static`, you can use any `RectanglePlus` to call the function:

```
test1.findLargest(test1,test2);
```

or

```
test2.findLargest(test1,test2);
```

Comment: it gives me strange output **oracleinterfaces.RectanglePlus@e48e1b** but compiles without any problems

Comment: The return value is of type `RectanglePlus`. To get meaningful output you will need to overwrite `toString()`.